# Is there any way to make a default mobile number in Sandbox Paypal?

Tags: paypal-sandbox

**If I type any number it should only show a default PH +63 which is Philippines default number.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Typically the default country is determined based on the browser's locale setting, e.g. topmost language in the Languages dropdown of chrome://settings/languages

For this donation flow you can also pass an `lc` variable with a default locale set, see https://developer.paypal.com/docs/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/#paypal-checkout-page-variables