# Where can I see and edit this mobile number dropdown in sandbox paypal?

Tags: paypal-sandbox

**If I type any number it should not have a dropdown and the default only is +63 which is the default mobile number of Philippines.**
[image]

[image]

**This is my paypal sandbox donate button code**

```
                  <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/donate" method="post" target="_top">
              <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="S5ANFRH53ER46" />
              <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" title="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" alt="Donate with PayPal button" />
              <input type="hidden" name="business" value="sb-clp2k5806930@business.example.com">
              <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="PHP">
              <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="PH">
              <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_PH/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1" />
              </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to change the layout or behavior of the PayPal login page in your screenshot.

As answered in your similar question, [Is there any way to make a default mobile number in Sandbox Paypal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67598851/is-there-any-way-to-make-a-default-mobile-number-in-sandbox-paypal) , the initial locale is taken from the browser and a default locale can also be set with `lc`, although it may not be used. The behavior of the login page will also depend on the GeoIP country, and cookies from previous logins.